# How can I copy artifacts from a agent on teamcity to my local machine when the build runs on that agent

Tags: xml, maven, teamcity, pom.xml, automated-deploy

I am working to automate the deployment process of my product for which I need to **copy .exe and .varfile to my local machine from an agent on TeamCity on which the build takes place**.I am trying to do it by writing scripts in **maven pom.xml**. I know that it would incorporate connecting first to localhost and defining ports which after many trials I have not been able to do it successfully. I am rather a beginner so, please comment out if any further clarification is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could publish all the .exe etc as artefacts and bundle them as a .zip file. Then from TC interface you can download them to local machine (part of it is manual though)

Other option would be to use ( add a build step) XCopy from CMD runner or PS script to copy the artifacts to any destination machine (relevant access could be required)